# MS Access - OLE Server Error....HELP!

Tags: database, ms-access, networking, ole

So I developed this access database application (just the back end), on a lap top, and now I have tried to move it onto a network drive. The purpose of this thing is to track data for metrics, so there is a lot of data (700k rows at 15 fields for main table), and it runs these top N queries that it builds charts with...

so i put it all on the network shared drive today and tried to run one chart..

the query seems to get stuck in the middle (just judging from the little progress bar on the bottom left side), and after waiting 5 minutes if I control break i get a message that says OLE Server Error.....

please don't tell me that it will work on a laptop and not on a network shared drive?

anyone know whats up with this?

Comment: What are the details of how you told the front end to access the back end?  Did you use a DSN in VBA, or some other method?  It's probably related to how you told it to connect.

Comment: Please post one of your (representaive) queries, and details of how you are connecting

Comment: One of the common mistakes is dragging huge volumes of data over the network; this is possibly the caus eof your problem...

Comment: The question is unanswerable without more details. Do you have one or more Access forms with charts/graphs? If you don't, then the OLE error is completely inexplicable based on any of the information you've supplied.

Comment: they are not on the same form however...in fact i do not have one form with more than one subform within it (chart or not). 

the starting form where i trip the event has a button that runs a query, then opens a seperate form (that is a chart form based on that query) that has vb that on open it automatically opens (first one, the rest on the active), acOLE copies itself into a powerpoint presentation (which is the purpose of that first button.

however this is not what I tried to do, i just tried to run a query by opening a chart (which i can do on the lap top no trouble).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine your queries and your connection method to ensure you are not dragging large volumes of data over the network to be processed/filtered in the front-end.

Comment: whenever I run one of these queries to produce the charts it has to "scan" the main table which is 700k rows @ 15 fields. now there are quite a bit of parameters per query (timeframe: month, quarter, fy) the type (ID, descrip, class, etc)....but to preform the top nth that is required by the client, i dont see any way around it

and this is just the "back-end"...meaning pre-split, pre-MDE...i just wanted to try to run some procedures to see if everything was placed back together properly (relationships, etc)....should this matter?

this is the trouble being a rookie....

Comment: problem solved. i am embarrassed to even say what the problem was here, but none-the-less is got resolved when I checked my queries, and trimmed the fat on some of the queried tables. thanks!